# Математические скобки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как изобразить на странице такие символы как на скриншоте?

[image: Фигурная скобка]

Имеется ввиду фигурная скобка и расположение последующих за ней элементов.

Comment: пишут что [можно](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2017/06/braces.html), еще наверно  наверно для этого можно и svg приспособить

Comment: да и css бордерами похоже тоже можно сделать

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему. И дайте вопросу нормальное название плиз.

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так годится? Раскрасишь сам.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  border-radius: .5em;
}

.badge {
  min-width: 2em;
  background: silver;
  margin: .25em;
}

.lbrace {
  border-left: 1px solid;
  padding-left: .25em;
  margin-left: .5em;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.lbrace:before {
  content: "";
  width: .5em;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class=row>
  <div class=badge>×1.5</div>
  <div class=lbrace>
    <div class=row>
      <div class=badge>В</div>
      <div class=badge>Ш×2</div>
    </div>
    <div class=badge>П</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Версия с более красивой скобкой (через фон, следующая лучше):

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  border-radius: .5em;
}

.badge {
  min-width: 2em;
  background: silver;
  margin: .25em;
}

.lbrace {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: black;
  border-right-color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white, white), linear-gradient(to right, black .75em, white .75em);
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
  padding-left: .25em;
  margin-left: .5em;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.lbrace:before {
  content: "";
  width: .5em;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class=row>
  <div class=badge>×1.5</div>
  <div class=lbrace>
    <div class=row>
      <div class=badge>В</div>
      <div class=badge>Ш×2</div>
    </div>
    <div class=badge>П</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

И ещё одна версия:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  border-radius: .5em;
}

.badge {
  min-width: 2em;
  background: silver;
  margin: .25em;
}

.lbrace {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
  padding-left: .25em;
  margin-left: .5em;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.lbrace:before {
  content: "";
  width: .5em;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.lbrace:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: .5em;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: .5em 0 0 .5em;
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<section class=row>
  <div class=badge>×1.5</div>
  <div class=lbrace>
    <div class=row>
      <div class=badge>В</div>
      <div class=badge>Ш×2</div>
    </div>
    <div class=badge>П</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Вроде идеально! Буду тестировать. Спасибо.

Comment: @Oma, а мой вариант Вас чем не устроил?

Comment: @humster_spb, ну мне твой вариант кажется менее универсальным - например, у тебя вторая строка абсолютом стоит. Не очень удобно расширяется на произвольное число строк. А скобку я могу хорошо прокрасить через градиент.

Comment: @Qwertiy, насчёт абсолюта - согласен. Но скобка, имхо, у меня вышла лучше :))

Comment: @humster_spb, погоди 5 мин, переделаю скобку.

Comment: @humster_spb, готово.

Answer (score 7):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 80px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-right: 0;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 0;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  left: -12px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.v, .p, .sh, .poltora {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
.v, .p {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
}
.v {
  background-color: #231f20;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sh {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #d1d6d9;
  height: 40px;
  width: 55px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
.p {
  background-color: #be2027;
}
.poltora {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 55px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f9bf5a;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  left: -70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="v">В</div>
  <div class="sh">Шх2</div>
  <div class="p">П</div>
  <div class="poltora">x1.5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS Вариант

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 200px;
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.content {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color:wheat;
  border-radius:5px;
}

.brace-l, .brace-r {
  width: 24px;
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.brace-l div, .brace-r div { 
  width: 10px; 
  height: 20px;
}
.brace-l div:nth-child(2),
.brace-r div:nth-child(6) { 
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
.brace-l div:nth-child(3),
.brace-r div:nth-child(7) { 
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
.brace-l div:nth-child(5), 
.brace-r div:nth-child(1) { 
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
.brace-l div:nth-child(8),
.brace-r div:nth-child(4){ 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="brace-l">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>

  <div class="content"></div>
 
  
  <div class="brace-r">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Тот же вариант, только с программно созданным css

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.brace').forEach(el => {
  el.innerHTML = Array(8).fill(0).map(() => '<div></div>').join('');
});
let s = document.createElement('style');
s.innerHTML = [[2,6],[5,1],[8,4],[3,7]].map((e,i) => 
  `.brace.l div:nth-child(${e[0]}), .brace.r div:nth-child(${e[1]}) {
      border-${i<2 ? 'top' : 'bottom'}-${i%2 ? 'right' : 'left'}-radius: 5px;
      border-${i%2 ? 'right' : 'left'}: 1px solid;
  }`).join('\n');
document.head.append(s);
```

```css
.brace {
  width: 24px;
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.brace div { 
  width: 10px; 
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="brace l"></div>
<div class="brace r"></div>
```

Comment: Скобочки красивенькие, но что-то кода полно...

Comment: @Qwertiy js-ом наверное много кода не будет, но и понятно не будет что генерится =)